# $H_k(E,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_k(X,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\pi:E\rightarrow X$ be a real vector fibrate of rank $n$. How to prove that
$$H_k(E,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_k(X,\mathbb{Z}).$$
approach: I consider it true that $X$ is a deformation rectract of $E$, it is true?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $X$ is the zero section of $E$. Then define a map on the fibers of $E$ given by $(v, t) \mapsto tv$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is homotopy equivalence. Try to show that $E$ can be retracted to the zero section (i.e., the image of the section $s:X\to E$ with $s(p)=0\in E_p$). What's the relationship between the zero section and $X$?